# Get just one entry of the selected item in observableCollection and showing in xaml C#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

im doing a app that show a listview of Services and if i select one it will triger this method.

```
  public void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = BindingContext as ServicosMenu;
        var ser = e.Item as Rota;

        vm.HideOrShowService(ser);
    }
```

So the thing is this will show a button call Details that will redirect me to a view of the details of the service that i selected. The problem is i don´t know how to bind that seleted item to the next View.

Exemple: Imagine today you got 2 Services, you choose one of them and it display the button details, you touch in that button and it redirect to this page :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ser="clr-namespace:AppQ4evo.Services"
             x:Class="AppQ4evo.Views.Detalhes">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ser:ServicosMenu/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout Spacing="10" Margin="10,10" >
    <Label Text="Detalhes do Cliente selecionado" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" Font="bold"/>

    <ListView  x:Name="details"             
               ItemsSource="{Binding OneSer }" 
               HasUnevenRows="True"   
              Margin="10,30">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>.....
```

With this xaml code i show above i get the details of the 2 services that come from my observableCollection ListSer, insted of just the one that i touched to see the details.

Any ideia of how i could do this to show just the details of the one item of the listview that i select?

Thanks for any Help!!

**EDIT1:**

```
The details button:

    private async Task Button_Clicked_DetalhesAsync(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Detalhes());
    }
```

The details

**EDIT2**

This is the class and view of the details:

Class:

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Detalhes : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Rota> Rote { get; set; }
    public Detalhes (Rota det)
    {
        Rote = new ObservableCollection<Rota>();
        Rote.Add(det);
      //  details.ItemsSource = Rote; this was a try did not work too
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

View:

```
<ListView  x:Name="details" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Rote}"
           HasUnevenRows="True"   
           Margin="10,30">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>...
```

You can see what is wrong in this??

Comment: please show the code you are using to navigate to the 2nd page

Comment: @Jason i edit up, its just a simple transaction with navigation page

Comment: pass the selected item in via the constructor

Comment: I'm here with other thinks but i am working on doing like you said via constructor, i jsut got one last question and than when it works/or not i  give here the feedback. My question is im using a listview to show one observableCollection os services, if i retrive one item(the selected one), can i steel use in xaml the listview tag to show the selected item?? @Jason thanks for the help

Comment: yes, just filter the list down to the selected item only

Comment: So this is my constructor of Details and he is getting the item select value, but it do not enter the listview, what am i doing wrong ?? Edit2 up in the main post @Jason